# Problem when upgrading from ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lost power during upgrade, how do I recover?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111563/lost-power-during-upgrade-how-do-i-recover)

while upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10, after completion of downloading packages, installation of packages was going on.Due to power cut, it was inevitable to me shutting my  computer down. Hence, the next steps of installing, cleaning and restarting could not be completed. The next time I logged in, I could see only a black screen. Please guide me to retrieve my ubuntu. (For your kind information, though I am a ubuntu lover, not a technically strong person)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I have faced before 4 Days. Grub boot loader has been failed to boot ubuntu. Fix it with using [this post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

A. IF you're able to boot in Ubuntu:-
Insert a Ubuntu 12.10 Live-CD/DVD and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Boot-Repair will launch. Select the 'Recommended Repair'.

B. IF you fail to see the Grub:-
Insert a Ubuntu 12.10 Live-CD/DVD and run the following commands:
    `$sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt` # XY is the drive, eg. sda or sda1

```
`$sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`

`$sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`

`$sudo chroot /mnt`

`$grub-install /dev/sdX`#X is drive number

`$update-grub`
```

Reboot.
Lemme know if it doesn't work as intended.