# My Upgrade From ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 got cancelled due to powercutoff

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lost power during upgrade, how do I recover?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111563/lost-power-during-upgrade-how-do-i-recover)

My upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 got cancelled due to the power being cut off, now Ubuntu is not starting.  What can I do? I run windows 7 and Ubuntu. So please help me to get out of this mess because all my files were in Ubuntu. And also I had installed a lot of apps in it. If I loose it I will be in trouble. Please help.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "not starting"?  Is Ubuntu completely refusing to boot, is it booting but you are only getting a command-line login prompt, or is it giving you a GUI but it is broken?  Please elaborate.  Also, is GRUB working properly (can you still boot Windows)?

Comment: Actually First time i opened it after power cutoff it showed me a page asking to mount something or skip dis task without mountuing but the computer got hanged so i had to restart it from restart button and after restarting now ubuntu after booting is just showing a black screen just before when usually the ubuntu desktop used to come.. and i am able to open my windows.. and is it possible to solve this problem by using a repairable live CD or a pendrive??

Answer (score 1):

Press ctrl alt f1 and then login there. after that type as

```
 sudo dpkg-configure -a
```

Comment: Know the feeling dude.

Answer (score 1):

1] If you're able to boot, but after login Unity doesn't load:
 It's possible that your GPU drivers are interfering; or that your hw isn't 3d-capable. Please post the result of the following command (press `CTRL+ALT+T`) :

`$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`

A. If you're using nVidia drivers: Run the following command to remove them, and reboot:

`$sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current`
`$sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current-updates`
`$sudo apt-get remove nvidia-experimental-304`
Or just open Synaptic and search for nvidia, delete everything that you see now.

Reboot the system. See if everything's working. Run this command to check if Unity-3D will work:

`$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`

Reboot again. Reinstall latest nVidia drivers:

$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates

B. If using AMD/ATI GPU drivers: Run the following command to remove them, and reboot:

$ sudo apt-get purge fglrx

Don't reinstall them as ATI cards currently don't support Unity-3D.

2] If you're unable to boot:
Insert a Ubuntu 12.10 Live-CD/DVD and run the following commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

Boot-Repair will launch. Select the 'Recommended Repair'.

3] IF you fail to see the Grub:- Insert a Ubuntu 12.10 Live-CD/DVD and run the following commands:

`$sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt` # XY is the drive, eg. sda or sda1

`$grub-install /dev/sdX`#X is drive number

`$update-grub`

Reboot. Lemme know if it doesn't work as intended.