# Upgrade install from 12.04 to 14.04 was interrupted

Tags: boot, upgrade, interrupts

My computer was in the process of upgrading from version 12.04 to 14.04. The computer was turned it off in the middle of installation, now I can't use my computer.  I don't know what to do now.  My brother put the previous version on for me and I am not very familiar with Linux.  Is there a way to fix this?  The computer starts with the options:

- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-74-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-74-generic (recovery mode)
- Previous Linux versions
- Memory test (memtest86+)
- Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
  I don't really have any idea what I'm doing.  I'm stumbling around in the dark and any help/advice would really be appreciated.

Comment: Try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/111563/lost-power-during-upgrade-how-do-i-recover/111567#111567).

Answer (score 0):

Best to du is to boot up you pc with an ubuntu live cd and put in an external hard drive Save all data frim there and than resinstall ubuntu compleatly . This may be the quickest and easiest fix for you.