# software updater not working for upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I tried to upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 using software updater. Half way through the installation my power and internet connection cut off. Now software updater does not seem to work at all, it seems to be looking, then the window grays out and nothing happens.

I tried another way. Downloaded 16.04 from the web, copied it to a USB drive. Restarted the machine and pressed F12 to select legacy USB boot, again nothing happened.

Any suggestions?
P.S. due to some physical problems I do not write code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lost power during upgrade, how do I recover?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/111563/lost-power-during-upgrade-how-do-i-recover)

Answer (score 0):

Does the computer have a CD Drive? If you burn the ISO it should copy over everything just fine and you still have the option to save your files.