# upgrading from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS failed due to power cut

Tags: 14.04

I was ugrading from my 14.04LTS to 16.04 LTS. Bymistakly i cutted my power. After that i tried to recover the configuration by using  sudo --configure -a(It worked)  but now it is showing only login window. Whenever i enter the password screen blinks twice and again come to login window.

Please guys help me to solve this issue

Comment: Backup your data and reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i searched on ask ubuntu for this query and i found the answer in ([Lost power during upgrade, how do I recover?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111563/lost-power-during-upgrade-how-do-i-recover))

i run the command sudo dpkg --configure -a which was stated in answer of that question

thanks to that guy