# Ubuntu won't boot after a power-cut during upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, chroot

I started an upgrade to (I believe) 18.04 and it got interrupted by a power-cut. I tried the solutions mentioned here --> [Lost power during upgrade, how do I recover?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111563/lost-power-during-upgrade-how-do-i-recover?newreg=d8cbf55399864e308f194fa2f4a6a06a) I have booted on ubuntu 16.04 Live cd.

My internal HD is encrypted and had a lock on it. I clicked it and it asked for my password. I have access to the HD which is mounted on /media/ubuntu with the name a293fd60-8bea-49cb-8f12-9cd4fe4d240b

When I try to chroot into it using

sudo chroot /media/ubuntu

It tells me the following chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory ... When I open my internal HD I can go into /bin and the bash file is located there.

How do I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

You said your drive is mounted to `/media/ubuntu/a293fd60-8bea-49cb-8f12-9cd4fe4d240b` but you're trying to `chroot /media/ubuntu/` and not to the drive.

So either

1. Try `chroot /media/ubuntu/a293fd60-8bea-49cb-8f12-9cd4fe4d240b` and edit all the other answer's `mount` commands to match
2. Or easier, just mount the drive to `/media/ubuntu` and follow the [other answer's commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111563/lost-power-during-upgrade-how-do-i-recover?newreg=d8cbf55399864e308f194fa2f4a6a06a) as-is.

Comment: good answer, I'll just add offical doc:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery