# Missing files after ubuntu update

Tags: 14.04

Good day! How to recover files after OS upgrade.
Yesterday (03/20/2021) the system started updating, but I suspended it. Then the computer froze and I had to restart it. After turning on, the files on the disk were gone. There are only files left on the desktop. Can they be restored and how?

Comment: If you are running 14.04 there is no long support on this site for this long past end of standard support version. You can post the question on https://superuser.com/

Comment: Why did you tag version 14.04? Did you really try to upgrade it to 16.04? If so, notice that 16.04 is going to be EOL (End of Life) starting month of April, and will no longer receive any updates or support. You'll have to try upgrading again. In your current condition I would just try to install a clean supported OS such as 18.04 or 20.04.

Comment: Regarding your file recovery: it really depends on what stage of the update you've terminated the process and what you're trying to recover. Even after recovering some files, any updated software or configuration files may have already changed. You'll need to use a backup. Recovery is sometimes possible when files are erased, not completely modified. in case of an upgrade, you could also perform a downgrade, but it would be even more problematic to downgrade to version 14.04 at this point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lost power during upgrade, how do I recover?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111563/lost-power-during-upgrade-how-do-i-recover) Your problem seems essentially the same.

Comment: No, you gave the wrong link, I have no problems with inclusion. Everything works. I just need to recover all my lost files. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was working during the update and the laptop started to freeze, so I had to pause the update. I thought to come back to this later.
Pizza, how can i use the backup or?

Comment: I have ubuntu 16.04 LTS