# Power off during release upgrade

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, upgrade

I was doing a do-release-upgrade from command line and it was taking a lot of time. So I left it overnight and in the morning I saw that the charge gas been exhausted and my laptop turned off. When I tried to reboot, grub menu appeared, but when I chose ubuntu , it just gets stuck at the screen that appears before file checking (where it shows the name of the company of laptop).

Is there any way to recover the system? I have a bootable usb stick with ubuntu 20.04. I booted from that and checked my /home partition. My files are safe. So I was thinking whether it is possible to just overwrite the root (/) partition and install ubuntu 20.04 on it while keeping my /home partition intact. Is it a feasible option? If yes, how?
P.S. I don't have any backup

Comment: Since you are able to boot from the USB, you can add a second USB device and backup your files...  After that you can try the install from the bootable USB, and you should be offered the option of installing over an existing install of Ubuntu.  But I would make a backup first.

Comment: Old, but still accurate: [Lost power during upgrade, how do I recover?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111563/lost-power-during-upgrade-how-do-i-recover)