# Cannot boot after power cut while upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, shutdown

While upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04, the power of my PC was lost. After that my PC is not booting into Ubuntu.

Comment: What is shown on screen? This has a huge bearing on what action to take.

Comment: why have you tagged `dual boot` is there something else you are not sharing with us? please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: It might also help if you're clear how you upgraded.. as 20.04 has two upgrade paths, (1) being to the next release which is 20.10, and (2) to the next LTS release after 22.04.1 has been released which is still in the future.. Neither upgrade path was from 20.04 to 21.04 so what you're describing won't occur if you use correct upgrade paths.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lost power during upgrade, how do I recover?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111563/lost-power-during-upgrade-how-do-i-recover)